# How can I build a stream/feed from multiple objects?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I want to build a notification stream on the front page of an application. Right now, I have models for News, Meetings, and Presentations. I want to combine these elements into a single object, perhaps called Events, so that I can then take the most recent 5 Events and display them on the front page. The output would be something like:

```
News Article: Submissions open starting April 1
Presentatiion: How to do stuff, the PDF
Meeting: April 15, Foo High School Gymnasium
```

The objects all implement an interface which requires getTitle, getBody and getCreationDate, so these functions are available to each object.

I don't want to simply merge the collections, as that gets messy. Is there any way to combine these objects into a single object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like a classic case for inheritance. You can create a model called Event.

```
class Event extends Model
```

Then your mentioned classes would extend the Event.

```
class Article extends Event
class Presentation extends Event
class Meeting extends Event
```

Then you could make a custom method on Event class. I think it would be simpler to write straightforward SQL than mess with Eloquent in your case, if you wish to avoid merging collections.

```
public function getUpcomingEvents()
{
    // something like that, you get the idea
    return DB::select('
        (SELECT title, body, CreationDate FROM articles LIMIT 5)
        UNION 
        (SELECT title, body, CreationDate FROM meetings LIMIT 5)
        ORDER BY CreationDate DESC LIMIT 5')->get();
}
```

This would keep your controllers clean and nice and models structure would represent the underlying logic.

Answer (score 4):

I'm going to go against what @Tadas said and say Eloquent might still be the best option here, using [polymorphism](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#polymorphic-relations). This way all of your events can be in a single table, easily selectable, and then your models can hold any special information that you need.

Have your tables set up like this:

```
event
    title
    body
    creation_date
    eventable_id
    eventable_type

news
    some_other_field1

meeting
    some_other_field2
```

And your models:

```
class Event extends Model
{
    /**
     * Get all of the owning imageable models.
     */
    public function eventable()
    {
        return $this->morphTo();
    }
}

class News extends Model
{
    /**
     * Get all of the staff member's photos.
     */
    public function events()
    {
        return $this->morphMany('App\Event', 'eventable');
    }
}

class Meeting extends Model
{
    /**
     * Get all of the product's photos.
     */
    public function events()
    {
        return $this->morphMany('App\Event', 'eventable');
    }
}
```

This method helps you out in a few different ways:

1. Getting events is really easy. Want the next 5 events coming up? `Event::where('event_date', '=>', new DateTime('today'))->orderBy('event_date', 'asc')->take(5);`
2. Easily get upcoming events for different models in a reusable way:

   ```
   News:whereHas('events', function($query) {
       $query->where('event_date', '=>', new DateTime('today'))->orderBy('event_date', 'asc')->take(5);
   })->get();
   ```
3. You also get the benefit of inheritance where you can have different fields in all of your models, but the base `Event` model can hold all of your generic information. And when you need model-specific information from the event object, you just call `$event->eventable-><whatever field you need>`
4. No raw queries needed. Just keep using the normal Laravel syntax for everything.